# Assigning pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a data structure which is storing necessary for me data.
I need to get pointer on memory of data structure field.

```
OAL_ErrorCode read_lwm2m_resource_str(lwm2m_context_t * lwm2mH,
                                      lwm2m_uri_t uri,
                                      char* dataToReturn)
{
lwm2m_data_t dataArray = {.id = uri.resourceId};
lwm2m_data_t* dataArrayPtr = &dataArray;
OAL_ErrorCode res;

res = _get_lwm2m_data_array(lwm2mH, uri, dataArrayPtr);
if (res != NO_ERROR)
{
    return res;
}

dataToReturn = (char*)dataArrayPtr->value.asBuffer.buffer;

return NO_ERROR;
}
```

---

```
char* strBuf;
result = read_lwm2m_resource_str(lwm2mH, uri, strBuf);
```

When I run programm in debugging mode and place breakpoint on return NO_ERROR inside read_lwm2m_resource_str(), dataToReturn pointing on right content, however after read_lwm2m_resource_str() was finished, strBuf has trash inside and pointing on different memory location.
What is wrong and how to make it works?

---

P.s **lwm2m_data_t**

```
struct _lwm2m_data_t
{
lwm2m_data_type_t type;
uint16_t    id;
union
{
    bool        asBoolean;
    int64_t     asInteger;
    uint64_t    asUnsigned;
    double      asFloat;
    struct
    {
        size_t    length;
        uint8_t * buffer;
    } asBuffer;
    struct
    {
        size_t         count;
        lwm2m_data_t * array;
    } asChildren;
    struct
    {
        uint16_t objectId;
        uint16_t objectInstanceId;
    } asObjLink;
} value;
};
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer-to-pointer: `char** dataToReturn` to modify the original pointer.

Comment: `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x=7; f(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` <- what number do you think is printed?